# How to do left join with group by in NET Core 3.0

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.0

As we know in .NET Core 3.0 a lot has changed and I'm building queries which don't run on client side memory.

I want to achieve a left join which count the items from child table keeping the parent intact if there no children against it.

**Desired output query:**

```
SELECT [c].[Type] AS [Name], COUNT([c0].Id) AS [Count]
FROM [CustomerTypes] AS [c]
LEFT JOIN [Customers] AS [c0] ON [c].[Id] = [c0].[CustomerTypeId]
WHERE [c0].[Id] IS NULL OR (([c0].[CompanyId] = 1) AND [c0].[CompanyId] IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY [c].[Id], [c].[Type]
```

**Entity Framework Queries**

```
from types in _dbManager.CustomerTypes
join customers in _dbManager.Customers
on types.Id equals customers.CustomerTypeId into tempJoin
from leftJoined in tempJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
where leftJoined == null || leftJoined.CompanyId == 1
group leftJoined by new { types.Id, types.Type } into grouped
select new TabCountBindingModel()
{
   Name = grouped.Key.Type,
   Count = grouped.Count(c => c != null)
}
```

**Output Query**

```
SELECT [c].[Type] AS [Name], COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM [CustomerTypes] AS [c]
LEFT JOIN [Customers] AS [c0] ON [c].[Id] = [c0].[CustomerTypeId]
WHERE [c0].[Id] IS NULL OR (([c0].[CompanyId] = 1) AND [c0].[CompanyId] IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY [c].[Id], [c].[Type]
```

No matter what I try I always end up with query above, either this or an exception.

**Tried these too**

```
from types in _dbManager.CustomerTypes
join customers in _dbManager.Customers
on types.Id equals customers.CustomerTypeId into tempJoin
from leftJoined in tempJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
where leftJoined == null || leftJoined.CompanyId == 1
group leftJoined by new { types.Id, types.Type } into grouped
select new TabCountBindingModel()
{
  Name = grouped.Key.Type,
  Count = grouped.Where(c=>c != null).Count()
}
Results in exception.
```

Comment: With EF (Core) you normally don't need such queries. With proper navigation properties the query should be simply `db.CustomerTypes.Select(t => new TabCountBindingModel { Name = t.Type, Count = t.Customers.Count(c => c.CompanyId == 1) })`. It will user correlated subquery rather than join and group by, but do you really care. Group by makes sense if you need more than one aggregate.

Comment: @IvanStoev you are right, but for the current situation i'm preferring the groupjoin over navigation properties.